# Might it be possible to create a meta-analysis for machine learning methods predicting something?

Tags: meta-analysis

I am working on a study trying to create a framework for tool selection for machine learning predicting a phenomenon. It should help researchers/practitioners choose the right algorithm for their case.

I am reading about meta-analyses and I am not sure I understand it throughout.
Might it be possible to end up with such a framework through a meta-analysis of previous studies?

P.S. I am stuck because it all makes sense if there it would be just one algorithm predicting the phenomenon and such I would organize the studies and create the analysis. With different methods, I am not sure how this can be done.

Thanks and sorry for a long post.